# Sort every few lines

Tags: multiple-lines, sort

I want to sort the following based on their keys

```
case IndexError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
case ValueError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
case RuntimeError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
case IOError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
```

so it becomes

```
case IOError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
case IndexError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
case RuntimeError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
case ValueError:
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, exc.str.c_str());
    break;
```

Essentially, I am only sorting the lines

```
case IOError:
case IndexError:
case RuntimeError:
case ValueError:
```

The contents of the other lines (the ones that do not begin with a `case`) do not matter but I want them to be sorted with the cases.

Comment: A side solution could be that, since the contents of the `case`s are similar, you could regenerate the whole thing. Get the sorted `*Error`s (from an `enum`? Maybe run through `sort(1)`?), then make a macro that converts `XError` to `case XError: PyErr_SetString(PyExc_XError, exc.str.c_str()); break;` and run it for all the enum values.

Comment: I haven't used this myself but vis.vim [claims](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/doc/vissort.txt.html) to do it. (Read section 4 at the link.) You can download vis.vim [here.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way: join the lines in the logical blocks before sorting.

In detail:

- mark the lines
- join the indented lines to the lines above: `:'<,'>s/\n /^A/`
- mark the lines again: `gv`
- sort them: `:'<,'>sort`
- mark the lines one more time: `gv`
- split the lines back and restore indentation: `:'<,'>s/^A/\r /g`

`^A` above is the character <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> (ASCII `SOH`).  It could be any character that doesn't appear in the lines to be sorted, but <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> fits the bill.  You can enter it as <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

**Idea:** Let's join the `n` number of lines under case to a single line.
Follow the process for all cases. Then, use sort to sort the cases. Then, cut those lines back and indent them.

**Steps:**

1)  Join `n` lines following `case` by typing this. (in your case, n is 3)

```
:g/case / normal! 3gJ
```

2) Select all such cases using visual mode. Press `v` ot `V` to select all cases. Press `:`. It will appear like `:'<,'>`. Type sort.

```
:'<,'>sort
```

3) Put the lines of case under it. Select them again by pressing gv.

```
:'<,'>s/\(;\|:\)    /&\r    /g
```

This splits the case lines. If lines arent indented properly, you can align them by selecting `gv` and then `==`.

This works for any number of lines, provided that you use the steps customised for your purpose.