# How to sort lines while preserving comment association

Tags: sort

Let's say I have a bunch of vim mappings (although it could be code in any language), each of which with a comment line or lines above them:

(using `#` not `"` so the comments get highlighted nicely)

```bash
# A comment
nnoremap <Leader>a ...
# D comment
nnoremap <Leader>d ...
# B comment
nnoremap <Leader>b ...
# H comment
nnoremap <Leader>h ...
# C comment
#   comment cont'd
#   comment cont'd
nnoremap <Leader>c ...
# F comment
nnoremap <Leader>f ...
# G comment
nnoremap <Leader>g ...
# E comment
nnoremap <Leader>e ...
```

How do I sort these lines, while preserving the association of comments with the first non-comment line below them?

i.e. I want this output:

```bash
# A comment
nnoremap <Leader>a ...
# B comment
nnoremap <Leader>b ...
# C comment
#   comment cont'd
#   comment cont'd
nnoremap <Leader>c ...
# D comment
nnoremap <Leader>d ...
# E comment
nnoremap <Leader>e ...
# F comment
nnoremap <Leader>f ...
# G comment
nnoremap <Leader>g ...
# H comment
nnoremap <Leader>h ...
```

Comment: This question isn't _identical_, but the same techniques apply: [Sort every few lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8542/sort-every-few-lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually select your lines, then run:

```
" join the comments and the related command
*g/^\s*#/,/^\s*[^# ]/-s/\n/\="\x01"

" sort the lines
*sort

" split back the lines
*s/\%x01/\r/g
```

To operate on the whole buffer rather than the visual selection, replace the `*` range with `%`.

Note that – in Vim – the comment leader is `"`, not `#`; unless you're writing a Vim9 script (`:h vim9-differences`).

Comment: I edited the comments a bit; OP was explicitly using lang-bash, and I’d rather not confuse people :)